# Implement facebook pixel to qualtrics survey

Tags: facebook, qualtrics, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to put in the Facebook pixel codes but nothing work. So I open my survey and do the right-click--> inspect[(picture 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWj0.png). Then I right-click on the head to edit HTML[(picture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6IHB.png) . I copy-paste the pixel code right before . All of this is based on Fb pixel instruction but when I put the survey link to check if the pixel is activated, it never works! Anyone ever done this before?
Thanks!!

Comment: When you change HTML through Inspect you are only changing it temporarily for the current session.  You need to add your html either to the survey header (under Look & Feel) if you want it on every page or to a question text's html if you only want it on one page.

Comment: Thank you Gibbons! You were right. I used Look & Feel and put the code in Custom CSS and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your facebook pixel code inside your page. You have paste the facebook pixel script with tracking events and initialize the pixel before fbq track. 
For example :-

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
// Insert Your Facebook Pixel ID below. 
fbq('init', 'FB_PIXEL_ID');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<!-- Insert Your Facebook Pixel ID below. --> 
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Share your warning screenshot that you'r facing in console..

Comment: Turns out I just put the code at the wrong place. Thanks for helping!